# compare two arrays and remove duplicates

Tags: javascript

code

```html
let arr = [{service:"test", program:[{pg:123, ag:123}]},
           {service:"test", program:[{pg:123, ag:123}]},
           {service:"test1", program:[{pg:1234, ag:1234}]}]
           
const result = arr.reduce((unique, o) => {
          if (!unique.some(obj => obj.service === o.service)) {
            unique.push(o);
          }
          return unique;
        }, []);

console.log(result)
```

> Here I am trying to compare the array of objects and remove duplicates but I was able to compare only first level of array of object. I need to compare the "**programs**" array of objects as well.

**Expected Output**

```
[{service:"test", program:[{pg:123, ag:123}]},
 {service:"test1", program:[{pg:1234, ag:1234}]}]
```

Comment: What is `tempObj`? What is `programs`?

Comment: sry tempobj is the array. I have updated the code.
program is another key-value pair which holds array of objects as. value

Comment: Your question was closed yesterday.

Comment: Here I need to check for same program and same service values and remove duplicates @trincot

Comment: Yes, your question was closed, because similar questions already have answers. See at the top.  But your question's code showed no attempt to do the same on programs. Just apply the same logic to those arrays as well.